# Saber a duração de uma música em MP3 com classes nativas do java?

Tags: java

Há alguma forma de saber atributos exclusivos de um arquivo mp3 com as classes nativas do Java? Só preciso da duração da música no caso.

Comment: aqui tem resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046669/how-do-i-get-a-mp3-files-total-time-in-java

Comment: Encontrei essa mesma pergunta em inglês, acredito que o seguinte link possa te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759331/finding-duration-of-an-mp3-file-in-java